# Django get access to foreign key of current object in views.py

Tags: python, django

I have three models:

```
Class Collection(models.Model):
    var_1 = .....
    var_2 = ....

Class Titles(models.Model):
    var_a = models.ForeignKey(Collection,
    related_name="has_titles", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    var_b = ...

Class OtherObject(models.Model):
    var_x = models.ForeignKey(Collection,
    related_name="has_other_object", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    var_y = ...
```

In views.py I use CBV DetailView with a form in it (using then formMixin or MultipleFormsMixin, but this is not the point).

So basically each Title is linked to a Collection by a ForeignKey and each OtherObject is linked to a Collection by a ForeignKey as well.

So, when the user is in a detail page of Title model, he has the posibility to fill in a form to add a OtherObject, that will then be displayed on the Collection detailView that is linked to the Title.

In other words, what I want is var_x = var_a of current Title :

```
if form.is_valid():
    new_other_object = form.save(commit=False)
    new_other_object.var_x = HERE I WANT TO GET var_a OF CURRENT OBJECT
    new_other_object.save()
```

So, as Title has a ForeignKey containing the ID to Collection it belongs to, I tried to use things such as self.get_object(). I read things such as using self.get_object().var_a could work but with all the different solutions I tried I got errors, mainly the error mentionning that object must be an instance of Collection.

How would you achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what model does your `DetailView` uses, can you provide more information about the view (perhaps the entire view if it is not that long).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My detailview uses the Title model. 
There is more to views.py but it does not really interfere with this problem I guess. 
I tried new_other_object.var_x = self.get_object().var_a for example but it does not work.

Comment: You only save the `new_fact`, not the `new_other`.

Comment: Sorry it is simply a writing error. I edit

Comment: Hey bro, please edit your post and include your **DetailView** class you need help with and also the **form** within your `forms.py` that you are evaluating. Without these at this point we can't help effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make a queryset:
new_other_object.var_x = Title.objects.get(pk=form['id'])
This way you get the object that is going to be the foregn key, then you insert into the foreign key field, and then you save, should work